# makefile with c++ classes

Tags: c++, makefile

I am trying to integrate my c++ project files via a **makefile** for hassle-free compilation. But I am facing some problems here. I have some c++ files like *main_prog.cpp* , *include.h* , *some_class.cpp* containing the usual program structure. Now my **makefile** looks like this:

```
all: main_proj.o some_class.o include.h
    g++ main_proj.o  some_class.o -o a.out

main_proj.o: main_proj.cpp some_class.o include.h
    g++ main_proj.cpp some_class.o -o main_proj.o

some_class.o: some_class.cpp include.h
    g++ some_class.cpp -o some_class.o
```

But this makefile does not work as it cannot find *main()* in *some_class.o*. 
The error is:

```
$ make
g++ some_class.cpp -o some_class.o 
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.9/../../../x86_64-linux-gnu/crt1.o: In function `_start':
(.text+0x20): undefined reference to `main'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
makefile:20: recipe for target 'some_class.o' failed
make: *** [some_class.o] Error 1
$
```

This is the problem. What should be the correct dependency order?

Answer (score 2):

The command

```
g++ main_proj.cpp some_class.o -o main_proj.o
```

tells GCC to compile the `main_proj.cpp` file *and link it* with the `some_class.o` object file and generate the executable program `main_proj.o`.

You should only compile the source file `main_proj.cpp` into an object file, which you do with the `-c` option. So the full rule and command should look something like

```
main_proj.o: main_proj.cpp include.h
    g++ main_proj.cpp -c -o main_proj.o
```

<sub>[Note that the `some_class.o` object file is not used anymore in this rule.]</sub>

Do the same for the generation of the `some_class.o` object file (i.e. add the `-c` flag).

---

There's also a problem with the first rule, which should really be something like

```
.PHONY: all
all: a.out

a.out: main_proj.o some_class.o
    g++ main_proj.o some_class.o -o a.out
```

---

After you got the makefile to work and build as you expect, you should continue to [read the `make` documentation](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/index.html), learn about implicit rules, variables, the automatic variables and much more. Then you can make your makefile very generic and easy to extend and reuse.

I also recommend you add more flags when creating the object files, to tell the compiler to generate more warnings. Warnings are like errors, but for things that are technically valid but may lead to problems when running. I personally always use *at least* the `-Wall` and `-Wextra` flags.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need an object file to generate another object file.
An object file is required only when you are generating an executable while generating and object file you just need to provide with source i.e. `*.h` and `*.cpp`

```
main_proj.o: main_proj.cpp include.h
   g++ main_proj.cpp -c -o main_proj.o
```